# Can someone plz tell me why this conditional formatting on google sheets does not highlight J8/9

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

I want the conditional formatting formula to apply to every merged box under deadline and the merged box to be highlighted if it is within 7 days of the deadline from today's date

Answer (score 1):

You should have used a dollar to fix Q4, otherwise when the formula is extended downwards the reference would become Q5, Q6 etc. and you would never get the right answer:

```
=and(L6="Incomplete",J6<(Q$4+7))
```

(I think also if your range starts at J6 you need the formula to start at J6).

[image]